# How to type a no-break space and a narrow no-break space?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, space

How to type a no-break space and a narrow no-break space with the keyboard (by a key combination) on Windows and Linux (Fedora for example) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows there are several built-in options and many 3d party software exist that assist with character input.
First of all you should find out the Unicode code point for the desired character, e.g. using online search. See this page for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin_space
Once you know the code point (e.g. hexadecimal `U+202F` for thin NB space), you can use general built-in options like "Character Map" application, or Alt+code input.  See here for description of methods:
http://www.fileformat.info/tip/microsoft/enter_unicode.htm

I personally  prefer 3-d party software: Autohotkey. It allows to bind the input command to any key and thus it is most effective and versatile solution for me.

Say, if I want to input thin NB space with Ctrl+Shift+Space combo, then I set up a script like this:

```
^+space::
    send {U+202f}
return
```

And so with any character or combination.

For Linux I can't say. There is no Autohotkey for Linux, but similar software might exist.